# Can Cockcroft-Walton circuit be multiplicative instead of additive?

Tags: high-voltage

The Cockcroft-Walton voltage multiplier can be used to increase an input voltage, for instance most commonly to double a voltage. However, adding on additional circuits would not continually double the voltage. What happens is that the voltage would be increased 3 times, then 4 times etc.

However, it seems to me that if you changed the arrangement of how the additional circuits are added such that the output of one led into the input of the other that you could continually double the voltage. That is second stage would 4 times the voltage, a third would 8 times it, a fourth would 16 times it, etc.

But I've never seen this arrangement done. Would this work?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft-Walton_generator

Comment: A theory (or idea) probably based on analysing it incorrectly BUT we only have your words and no circuit diagram. You mention "if you changed the arrangement of how the additional circuits are added" but this means SFA without a circuit so, show the circuit and make a big name for yourself if it turns out you were right. I am sceptical in case you didn't notice!

Comment: And besides, losses across discrete components add up quickly. If you only need a few milliamps at high voltages it's one thing, but unleashing 1000 amps at 12460 volts ac - well, build a generator for that. If the better part of valor is discretion,  then the better part of engineering may be economics.

Comment: Simply the fact that nobody has done this before should be a strong clue that it isn't as easy as you think.  These things and the theory behind them have been around for a quite a long time.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to follow the link to Wikipedia that you included in your question and learn how the circuit actually works.

There are two problems with what you propose.

1) The multiplier uses the incoming AC signal coupled through the capacitors in each successive stage. The peak-to-peak voltage of that incoming AC waveform is what gets added to the DC voltage already at that node.

2) The output of the multiplier is DC. You can't feed DC into a multiplier of this type.

Answer (score 1):

For your idea to work you need something substantially different than a Cockroft-Walton voltage multiplier.

A C-W multiplier inherently works on AC.  The peak to peak amplitude (minus the diode drops) is added to the output each stage.  This is fundamentally a addition.  The input p-p amplitude isn't changed, so the same amount will be added to the accumulated voltage each stage.  One way to think of a C-W is as a bunch of charge pumps cascaded.

Having the voltage double each stage would also negate a nice property of a C-W, which is that the components of each stage only need to be able to handle a fixed voltage, regardless how high the voltage ultimately gets at the end.